# Finding Solution sets of $1<\frac{x+1}{2x-1}<3$ in timed exam

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

What is the solution sets of $1<\frac{x+1}{2x-1}<3$?

$1) (0.6,1.5)\qquad\qquad2)(0.8,1.2)\qquad\qquad3)(1,2)\qquad\qquad4)(0.8,2)$

It is a problem from timed exam. so I should solve this as fast as possible. by plugging in numbers in the choices I realized for $x=0.8$ the function is $\frac{1.8}{0.6}=3$ and by plugging in $x=2$ we have $\frac{3}{3}=1$. so I think the answer is fourth choice.

Is it a valid solution for the problem?

Comment: Consider $0 < \frac{x+1}{2x-1} - 1$ and $\frac{x+1}{2x-1} -3 < 0$, sum fractions and see what happens in the intervals before and after the expression turns to 0.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using process of elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write $$\frac{x+1}{2x-1}=\frac12\frac{2x+2}{2x-1}=\frac12\left(1+\frac{3}{2x-1}\right)$$
Then take the given inequality, multiply by $2$, subtract $1$, divide by $3$, and invert to get
$$3>2x-1>\frac35$$
Add $1$ and divide by $2$ to get
$$2>x>\frac45$$

The point is, in that first step to get it written with one "$x$", not two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct.

Here is a quick and sure way. the inequation id equivalent
$$\frac{x+1}{2x-1}-1=\frac{2-x}{2x-1}>0$$
whose solution is $S_1= (\frac 12,2)$,

And
$$3-\frac{x+1}{2x-1}=\frac{5x-4}{2x-1}>0$$
whose solution is $ S_2=(-\infty,\frac 12)\cup(\frac 45,+\infty)$.

So the answer is $S_1\cap S_2=(0.8,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to realize is that $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is always monotonic.

In fact it is equal to $\dfrac ac+\dfrac{cd-ba}{c(cx+d)}=cst+\dfrac{cst}{cx+d}\ $ this means it has the same behaviour as $\dfrac 1{cx+d}$ which is monotonic

Rem: *on each of the two intervals apart from the discontinuity $x=-d/c$*.

This is why your method of examining the values taken at the bounds of the proposed intervals is completely justified, since the function is monotonic these values represent the min and the max of the function on the interval.

The discontinuity of $2x-1$ is $x=\frac 12$ but none of the proposed intervals contains it, so you are safe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. about last paragraph I think it is not important to know where discontinuity is, because the range of the function is $\mathbb{R}-\{\frac12\}$ and it is injective function (according to graph) .so for one value of $x$ it is $1$ and for one value is $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $2x-1 > 0$ (and none of the chooses allow otherwise)

$2x - 1 < x+ 1 < 6x -3$

$x+1 < 6x -3$ and $4< 5x$ so $\frac 45 < x$.

And $2x -1 < x + 1$ so $x < 2$.  SO 4) is the choice.

Or.....

$\dfrac {x+1}{2x - 1} = \dfrac {x -\frac 12+ \frac 32}{2x-1} = \dfrac 12 +\dfrac{\frac 32}{2x-1}$.

So $1 < \dfrac 12 + \dfrac {\frac 32}{2x-1} < 3$

$\frac 12 < \dfrac {\frac 32}{2x-1} < 2\frac 12$

$1 < \dfrac 3{2x-1} < 5$

$1 > \dfrac {2x-1}3 >\frac 15$

$3 > 2x -1 > \frac 35$

$4 > 2x > \frac 85$

$2> x > \frac 45$ so 4) is the choice.